# Beginner Simple Mileage Calculator: Can't return Var

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to educate myself and look at other work on how to get this simple calculator to work with JS. I have debugged it via google chrome and I can't identify what fundamentals I am missing;

```js
var theForm = document.forms["mmacalc"];

function getsjourn()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["mmacalc"];
    var sjourn = theForm.elements["sjourn"];
    var smile =0;
    if(sjourn.value!="")
    {
        smile = parseInt(sjourn.value);
    }
    
    return smile;
}

function getrjourn()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["mmacalc"];
    var rjourn = theForm.elements["rjourn"];
    var rmile =0;
    if(rjourn.value!="")
    {
        rmile = parseInt(rjourn.value);
    }
    
  return rmile;
}

function getmilalallow()
{
    var tmile = sjourn() * rjourn() ;
 
    document.getElementById('tjourn').innerHTML =
                                     "Your total mileage is"+tmile;
    var milal = sjourn() * rjourn() * 0.25 ;
 
     document.getElementById('mmac').innerHTML =
                                      "Your MMA Claim is: £"+milal;
                                       
}
```

```html
<script type="javascript" src="formulacalculations.js"></script>
<form name="mmacalc" id="mmacalc" action="" method="post" target="_self">
    <label for ="sjourn"> Single Journey Mileage </label>
    <input type="text" id="sjourn" name="sjourn" value="" onclick="calculateTotal()">
    <br><hr>
    <label for ="rjourn"> Amount of Return Journeys </label>
    <input type="text" id="rjourn" name="rjourn" value="1" onclick="calculateTotal()">
    <br><hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="getmilalallow()">
    <br><hr>
    <div class="tjourn" id="tjourn"></div>
    <div class="mmac" id="mmac"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I made a single snippet from your two code samples. The code you provided does not have a `calculateTotal` function, first of all. Add that and we can see if we can help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a form for this is unwise, because when you click the `input[type=submit]` button, it will POST the data and refresh the page. You can get around this with `event.preventDefault()`, but there's no need - we will change it to a div for this. Use a `form` when you need to send data to a server - for client-side stuff, avoid forms.

Also, you were binding your logic to the text inputs' `onclick` eventListener, so whenever a user tapped on a textfield it would do the computation. I removed those eventListeners and moved it to the submit button instead, so the UI updates when a user taps the button.

We will combine all of the logic into one function, `updateTotals`, which will calculate the total and update the `innerHTML` of the two paragraphs when the button is clicked.

```js
var theForm = document.forms["mmacalc"],
      sjourn = document.getElementById('sjourn'),
      rjourn = document.getElementById('rjourn'),
      tjourn = document.getElementById('tjourn'),
      mmac = document.getElementById('mmac');

function updateTotals() {
  let total = sjourn.value * rjourn.value;
  
  tjourn.innerHTML = `Your total mileage is ${total}`,
  mmac.innerHTML = `Your MMA Claim is ${total*0.25}`;
}
```

```html
<div id="mmacalc">
  <label for="sjourn"> Single Journey Mileage </label>
  <input type="text" id="sjourn" name="sjourn" value="">
  <br>
  <hr>
  <label for="rjourn"> Amount of Return Journeys </label>
  <input type="text" id="rjourn" name="rjourn" value="1">
  <br>
  <hr>
  <button onclick="updateTotals()">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div class="tjourn" id="tjourn"></div>
  <div class="mmac" id="mmac"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Christian - Once you reshaped it and gave me a foundation, I found understood the structure and started to expand further and play with it.